# Predicted dependent variable with some conditions in R

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, poisson-regression

I have a data including province, district, **number of household in need (nohhinneed) (dependent variable)**, a score about socioeconomic status (ses), total number of households (sumhh), etc.

When I make a model, predicted results can be negative as well but I'm predicting number of households in need, it cannot be negative. And it cannot be more than total number of households.

I tried linear model at first but I saw some negative predictions for dependent variable. And then I tried poisson model but the predictions are more than total number of households.

How can I add constraints to make predictions?

My model is like below:
nohhinneed = ses + sumhh + ...

Comment: Can you say more about the variable `nohinneed`?  is it bounded?

Comment: Think about this way, there are provinces and districts. In those districts there are households and some of them are households in need. I'm sure that there are more number of household in need in real. For example, a district has 100 households in total but 23 of them are hh in need. I want to make a model to predict hh in need and it should be less than 100. To correctly predict this, I use socioeconomic status, as well.

Comment: Have you looked at binomial (with the i.e. Y out of N households; aka "logistic regression") or beta (proportion between 0 and 1 that cannot be exactly 0 or 1) regression?

Comment: Actually, I need a number, 0 and 1 are not my intention to find. After prediction, I want to say in this district, there are 13 households in need but my prediction says it should be indeed 41 or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure the predictions (y-hat values) are on the response level & not on the scale of the linear predictor?  What link did you use?  By default a negative binomial model will use a log link.  In that case, it isn't mathematically possible to get negative predictions (on the response scale).  Can you paste in your function call and the output?